# How to solve TypeError: result.select is not a function in a Node.JS, Express JS and MongoDB App

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating a store API.

I am trying to filter out the result using the field from req.query and select.  Everything else works fine except the select.

Error: **TypeError: result.select is not a function**

```
if (field) {
        const sortField = field.split(",").join(" ");
        result = result.select(sortField);
    }
```

[image]

Not sure why is the select not a function.

Comment: Hi, please do not use imgs for errors/code. Read here: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)

Answer (score 0):

From the image, looks like `result` is a unresolved promise when you call the `select`.
Also, there's no `select` method for an array (witch I believe, is what you're trying to filter out); instead you can use `filter`

Try this:

```js
let newResult;
if (field && result) {
        const sortField = field.split(",").join(" ");
        newResult = result.filter(x=> x === sortField);
}
```